# Whats exactly Ether unit return web3.eth.estimateGas, wei, gwei ...?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

I am testing with function  **[web3.eth.estimateGas](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.8/web3-eth.html?highlight=estimateGas#estimategas)** and is not clear what Ether unit is returning.

Looks like it's gwei, but my final calculations don't match.

In my code, the EGAS returned is 84753.
I think it is too little to be wei or gwei

How can I convert to wei the uint returned by estimateGas function?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer, but if you go to the source code "eth.py", function signature says it's returning **"Wei"**:

```
def estimateGas(self, transaction: TxParams, block_identifier: BlockIdentifier=None) -> Wei:
```

This is actually **very** misleading. I tested this out. It returned "239231", but in what unit? You should interpret the number as follows:

```
gas_estimate
239231
gas_price = w3.eth.gasPrice
gas_price
5000000000000
gas_estimate_wei = gas_estimate * gas_price
gas_estimate_wei
1196155000000000000
gas_estimate_in_coin = gas_estimate_wei / (1000000000 * 1000000000)
gas_estimate_in_coin
1.196155
```

How you should interpret the numbers are as follows:

gas_estimate = 239231 units

gas_price = 5000,000,000,000 **wei per unit**

Or

gas_price = 5000 **gwei per unit**

So, *"gas_estimate_in_coin"* = 1.196155. Now, what "**coin**"? It depends on the chain you're interacting with. If you're interacting with CRONOS, that's 1.196155 **CRO**, which is about 49.9 cents in USD (CROUSDT = 0.4168 on 20220413)! On the other hand, on Ethereum mainnet, that's 1.196155 **ETH**, which changed everything!!!

***References***

(Wei, Gwei, ETH conversion)

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html?highlight=estimate_gas#web3.eth.Eth.estimate_gas

https://blog.oasis.app/gas-fees-a-small-guide/

https://www.thebalance.com/gwei-5194614

https://norman-lm-fung.medium.com/interact-with-cronos-single-usdc-lp-with-web3-py-1e14c62a0d9c

Similar question: [Smart Contract - approve function: wad](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/126085/smart-contract-approve-function-wad)

Answer (score 0):

It returns the gas *limit*, not the gas price. Gas limit is how many units of gas to use at most, and a unit of gas is your gas price.

Comment: I dont want to know te gasPrice. There is a web3js function for that. I need to know the real fee for a transaccion in Wei.

Comment: For that you need to use ```web3.eth.getGasPrice```.

Comment: getGasPrice is a fixed value by the chain. I dont need that.

Comment: What? It literally returns the thing you want, the gas price in Wei. Also it is NOT a fixed value. Try multiplying ```estimateGas``` with ```getGasPrice``` for a transaction's total fee in wei.

Comment: this awnser is prerry correct to what was asked,  why somebody downvoted it.
estimateGas returns the gas limit, its unit is gas 'unit'.